# How to randomise the columns in a datagridview and saving it back to a txt file? (Visual Studio Forms, .NET Framework)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently trying to make a "randomizer" program for the game 'Motorsport Manager', where you import a text file into a Datagridview, then clicking on the randomise button, and then save it back to the same format, so you have a fresh file with the columns in a random other.
(If possible I would like to specify which columns/rows not to randomise so the file doesn't break)

I have tried for several days now but only got as far as saving [the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nYAF.png), but not with comma's like in the original file. This does not include the randomizer part as I have no idea how I would do that. I searched the internet for a solution but to no avail.

This is how the text files look before importing look like

[image]

This is how the file looks in the Datagridview

[image]

This is the code I used for that form.

```
    private void BTN_LDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Title = "Browse Drivers.txt File",
            CheckFileExists = true,
            CheckPathExists = true,
            DefaultExt = "txt",
            Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true,
            ReadOnlyChecked = true,
            ShowReadOnly = true,
        };

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            Helper.file = textBox1.Text;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = Helper.DataTableFromTextFile(textBox1.Text);

        }
    }

    private void BTN_BTM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        var Form1 = new Form1();
        Form1.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        Form1.Show();
    }

    private void BTN_STT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                writer.Write("\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + ",");
            }

        }
        writer.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
    }

}
```

Anyone out here that can help me out? I'm not good with coding but willing to try and learn. :) 
(Also I hope I made this post correctly, it's my first time lol)

Thank you in advance,
Straatham

Comment: What do you mean by "the columns in random order"? Do you just want to move the columns around, or do you also want to change row data?

Comment: According to your recent reply, it seems that you want to randomly sort rows in datagridview. Here is a workaround: 1.Define a DataTable to store the data in the datagridview. 2.Declare an additional ID column to store the order of the rows 3.Call Random() to assign values to IDs 4.Sort DataTable by ID. 5.Import the DataTable into the DataGridview (note that ID column is excluded) Maybe you can refer to this [simple demo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/zh-TW/c1facf66-2f1e-4f3e-b4b1-42363e9a2439/datatabledataview21487201973691434892385682723130340254902420721966?forum=233).